# I can add favorite / ignored tags for other users?

Tags: support, user-accounts, moderators

While viewing another user's profile page, I saw I apparently have the ability to add favorite or ignored tags for them:

[image: screenschot]

(Parts blacked out for privacy reasons.)

I didn't attempt to add any tags, so I'm not sure whether it would actually work; either way, I shouldn't be seeing this.

**Edit:** I'm also seeing the following on the "accounts" tab:

[image: screenshot 2]

I know that was a problem before on another site, but I thought it was fixed!

Comment: It's a moderator thing. This should probably go to meta.stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm a mod on Bicycles, and I never noticed this until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tom notes, you (as a moderator) get a privileged view of user accounts, allowing you to see and potentially modify *almost* all information available to the user.

This can be quite useful for answering [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions. Perhaps a user is confused as to why certain questions aren't appearing for him - a quick check will show you that he is ignoring the tag common to those questions.

*Normally* you should treat this as read-only; users tend to get upset when you mess with their accounts. But the ability is there, should you ever need to use it.

(And per the moderator agreement, you should refrain from ever discussing *any* private user information publicly - no matter how benign it might seem).

Comment: Alrighty, interesting. I had no idea mods could do this.

Answer (score 1):

I belief this allows you to help the user when he has trouble performing these actions themselves, at least that's what I think for the association system. As I don't think there is really a case where one would need help with favorite or ignored tags, but I guess it does happen...

But as @BenAlpert says check it on Meta.SO, because it is either [status-by-design](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-by-design) or it is really a [bug](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).